# Redshift/PSQL Group By Error on Aggregate

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the following query I keep receiving the error `[42803] ERROR: column "distributed_stats_storage_facebook_post.impressions" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

I can't figure out for the life of me why I would get this error.

```
WITH qualified_posts AS (
    SELECT
      platform_data_api_post.external_id,
      platform_data_api_account.display_name
    FROM platform_data_api_post
      INNER JOIN platform_data_api_account
        ON platform_data_api_account._id = platform_data_api_post.account_id
      INNER JOIN platform_data_api_platform
        ON platform_data_api_platform._id = platform_data_api_account.platform_id
      INNER JOIN platform_data_api_post_type
        ON platform_data_api_post_type._id = platform_data_api_post.post_type_id
      INNER JOIN distributed_stats_storage_facebook_post
        ON distributed_stats_storage_facebook_post.external_object_id = platform_data_api_post.external_id
    WHERE platform_data_api_platform.name = 'facebook'
          AND platform_data_api_post_type.name = 'shared_link'
          AND platform_data_api_post.published >
              (DATE_PART(epoch, DATEADD(day, -10, DATE_TRUNC('day', GETDATE())))) :: BIGINT
    GROUP BY 1, 2
    HAVING max(distributed_stats_storage_facebook_post.stories_by_action_type__share) > 0
           AND max(distributed_stats_storage_facebook_post.consumptions_by_type__link_clicks) > 0
),

impressions_percentiles_by_page AS (
      SELECT qualified_posts.external_id,
             qualified_posts.display_name,
             max(impressions) AS impressions,
             ntile(20) over (PARTITION BY qualified_posts.display_name order by impressions) AS impressions_percentile
      FROM  distributed_stats_storage_facebook_post
      INNER JOIN qualified_posts ON qualified_posts.external_id = distributed_stats_storage_facebook_post.external_object_id
      WHERE distributed_stats_storage_facebook_post.external_object_id IN (qualified_posts.external_id)
      GROUP BY 1, 2
  )

SELECT * FROM impressions_percentiles_by_page;
```

I believe that this section here is where the error is originating from, but it seems like it is asking me to group by on an aggregate function?

```
impressions_percentiles_by_page AS (
      SELECT qualified_posts.external_id,
             qualified_posts.display_name,
             max(impressions) AS impressions,
             ntile(20) over (PARTITION BY qualified_posts.display_name order by impressions) AS impressions_percentile
      FROM  distributed_stats_storage_facebook_post
      INNER JOIN qualified_posts ON qualified_posts.external_id = distributed_stats_storage_facebook_post.external_object_id
      WHERE distributed_stats_storage_facebook_post.external_object_id IN (qualified_posts.external_id)
      GROUP BY 1, 2
  )
```

**What is even more strange to me is that when I sub out the `impressions_percentiles_by_page` clause with a different metric I am working with.  The full query below works fine.  Apart from the columns they are querying these two clauses are the same**

```
WITH qualified_posts AS (
    SELECT
      platform_data_api_post.external_id,
      platform_data_api_account.display_name
    FROM platform_data_api_post
      INNER JOIN platform_data_api_account
        ON platform_data_api_account._id = platform_data_api_post.account_id
      INNER JOIN platform_data_api_platform
        ON platform_data_api_platform._id = platform_data_api_account.platform_id
      INNER JOIN platform_data_api_post_type
        ON platform_data_api_post_type._id = platform_data_api_post.post_type_id
      INNER JOIN distributed_stats_storage_facebook_post
        ON distributed_stats_storage_facebook_post.external_object_id = platform_data_api_post.external_id
    WHERE platform_data_api_platform.name = 'facebook'
          AND platform_data_api_post_type.name = 'shared_link'
          AND platform_data_api_post.published >
              (DATE_PART(epoch, DATEADD(day, -10, DATE_TRUNC('day', GETDATE())))) :: BIGINT
    GROUP BY 1, 2
    HAVING max(distributed_stats_storage_facebook_post.stories_by_action_type__share) > 0
           AND max(distributed_stats_storage_facebook_post.consumptions_by_type__link_clicks) > 0
),

    share_percentiles_by_page AS (
      SELECT
        qualified_posts.external_id,
        qualified_posts.display_name,
        max(stories_by_action_type__share) AS shares,
        ntile(20)
        OVER (PARTITION BY qualified_posts.display_name
          ORDER BY shares)                 AS share_percentile
      FROM distributed_stats_storage_facebook_post
        INNER JOIN qualified_posts
          ON qualified_posts.external_id = distributed_stats_storage_facebook_post.external_object_id
      WHERE distributed_stats_storage_facebook_post.external_object_id IN (qualified_posts.external_id)
      GROUP BY 1, 2
  )
SELECT * FROM share_percentiles_by_page;
```

Comment: It's because you are using a window function and referencing that field, which you are also aggregating.

Comment: @nicarus how come I don't get an error with the second query which does the same thing?